# Luxon Creating DateTimes in a zone difficulties

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone, luxon

I'm having trouble creating timezones in a zone. Using Luxon and nodejs Below is my code and below that the logs I'm getting:

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
let luxDate = DateTime.fromISO("2021-10-28T16:00:00", {zone: "Europe/London"});
console.log(luxDate.toString())
```

This then logs:
2021-10-29T04:00:00.000+01:00

When it should log
2021-10-28T16:00:00.000+01:00

Which I don't understand, this is an 11 hour actual offset whereas Europe/London should just be +1

I've been trying to follow this guide but it doesn't appear to be working:
https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/zones

I'm doing this on an azure server which I believe sets everything in UTC. Am I doing anything stupid here?

Thanks,

Comment: it should log `"2021-10-28T16:00:00.000+01:00"`

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm not sure why it isn't. Will add that to the question to make it clearer

Comment: is it something with the version

Comment: I tried reinstalling using npm install --save luxon via npm
In my package.json the version is 2.0.2

Comment: weird. i tested with the npm runkit  2.0.2 version